# Linq to Sql Datacontext primary key not set

Tags: c#, linq

I created in my application a dataclasses context and want to insert in my database some entries via LINQ but it says

> Can't perform Create, Update, or Delete operations on
>   'Table(discipline)' because it has no primary key.

But I already marked a column in the designer as identity column to true;

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a column as IDENTITY doesn't mean that it is also the PRIMARY KEY of your table.
You need to set it explicitily using SSMS interface of through a sql statement

You can set it when creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Nations
(
    NationID int IDENTITY(1,1), 
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CapitalCity varchar(255)
    PRIMARY KEY (NationID)
)
```

or using the ALTER TABLE statement

```
ALTER TABLE Nations ADD PRIMARY KEY (NationID)
```